# Proving a polynomial is positive

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

How do I prove that the polynomial
$$ f(x) = x^5-x^3/2-x+4/5 $$
is positive for all real numbers $x > 0$? One obvious way is to show that
$$ f'(x) = 5x^4-3x^2/2-1 $$
has a unique positive root $x_0$ for which $f(x_0) > 0$ and $f''(x_0) > 0$, so the minimum of $f$ must be $f(x_0) > 0$, but the computation of the root and then inserting it into $f, f''$ seems so inelegant to me. I tried completing the square but to no avail. Any elegant ideas?

Comment: Solving your derivtaive equation is not difficult, as it is quadratic in $z=x^2$.

Comment: @lulu Indeed it isn't, I have solved it, but it is inelegant to me. There may be a nicer approach.

Comment: @chaos  I tend to doubt it.  Barring arithmetic error (always possible), $f(x_0)\approx .0712$ which is pretty small.  Change the $\frac 45$ slightly, and this could easily have been negative.  But anything is possible.

Comment: Note:  there is no need at all to check the sign of $f''(x_0)$, where $x_0$ is the unique positive root of $f'(x)=0$.  It's obviously a minimum, since $f(x)\to +\infty$ as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that remark @lulu, but I do find it inelegant to have to plug the root of $f'$ into $f$ - if the constants are nastier than here, and you have no access to a calculator, how do you show that $f(x_0) > 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By AM-GM:
$$10x^5-5x^3-10x+8=(3x^5-5x^3+2)+(7x^5-10x+6)\geq$$
$$\geq5\sqrt[5]{(x^5)^3\cdot1^2}-5x^3+\left(5\sqrt[5]{7\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^4}-10\right)x>0.$$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer, there is a negative term $-5x^3$ in there.

Comment: @chaos  $5\sqrt[5]{(x^5)^3\cdot1^2}-5x^3=0.$

Comment: Haha yes indeed, I will read through your answer again and see how you derived each step.

Comment: Wow, this is a crazy answer. How did you come up with this splitting / think that AM-GM would work? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @chaos  I just tried to use AM-GM and it turned out.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$x^5-\frac{x^3}{2}-x+\frac{4}{5} = x \left({x}^{2}-\frac 34 \right)^{2}+x \left(x-\frac  3 4 \right) ^{2}+\frac 32 \left( x-{\frac{17}{24}} \right)^{2}+{\frac{91}{1920}}>0.$$
See [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h479486p3302291).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, but I don't follow how you derived it based on the link you sent. Could you explain a little more in the solution if you can?

Answer (score 0):

For $x\ge1$ the result is trivial since

$$f'(x) = 5x^4-\frac 32x^2-1 \ge 5x^2-\frac 32x^2-1=\frac 7 2x^2-1>0$$

then for $0<x=\frac1y<1$ with $y>1$ we have

$$x^5-x^3/2-x+4/5>0 \iff 8y^5-10y^4-5y^2+10>0$$

and by subsuquent elementary completion of the squares

$$8y^5-10y^4-5y^2+10=(8y^5-16y^4+8y^3)+6y^4-8y^3-5y^2+10=$$

$$=8y^3(y-1)^2+(6y^4-12y^3+6y^2)+4y^3-11y^2+10=$$

$$=8y^3(y-1)^2+6y^2(y-1)^2+(4y^3-8y^2+4y)-3y^2-4y+10=$$

$$=8y^3(y-1)^2+6y^2(y-1)^2+4y(y-1)^2-3(y-1)^2-10(y-1)+3>$$

$$>18y(y-1)^2-3(y-1)^2-10(y-1)+3=(18y-3)(y-1)^2-10(y-1)+3>$$

> $$>15(y-1)^2-10(y-1)+3>0$$